# C# VS2010 Determine in application whether being debugged

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010, system.diagnostics

Is there a chance to determine in an C# application whether it is currently being debugged? The idea is to ignore e.g timeouts, or to provide additional information.

Just to make this clear, I am **not** talking about the conditional compiler flag `DEBUG`. This allows me to decide how the code shall be compiled. It gives no information about whether it is run in a debugger or not.

I need to decide at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) flag to determine this.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, never came across this one. Very useful! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I cannot mark both as answer.

Answer (score 7):

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, never came across this one. Very useful! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I cannot mark both as answer.